# Script to mount files local to gdrive

Tags: linux, script, mount, sharing

I have that kind of script which worked with virtual box but now I did not know about the new `Mounttype` ?

Here the script :

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# mount & copy  -  Mount the Virtualbox shared folder and copy files to PC

Mounttype=vboxsf    #mount for gdrive??
Mountname=  ?????     #mountname ?
Mountpoint=/home/james/gdrive/OpenWrt_builds/IPQ806X_master
BinDir=bin/targets/ipq806x/generic

echo Check for existing mount of the shared folder $Mountpoint
df | grep $Mountpoint
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo Mounting $Mountpoint as $Mountname...
  sudo mount -t $Mounttype $Mountname $Mountpoint
  [ "$?" -ne 0 ] && echo "Sudo/mount failed." && exit 1
fi

echo "\nCopy from $PWD ..."
cp $BinDir/*bin $Mountpoint
sleep 2
cp $BinDir/*img $Mountpoint
sleep 2
cp $BinDir/ath10k* $Mountpoint
sleep 1
cp $BinDir/*patch $Mountpoint
sleep 1
cp $BinDir/*sh $Mountpoint
sleep 1
cp $BinDir/*txt $Mountpoint
sleep 1
cp $BinDir/*config.init $Mountpoint
cp $BinDir/*config $Mountpoint
echo done.
```

I changed the mountpoint to my gdrive location but need to change the mounttype, here my problem.

[mount man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're trying to mount your host PC's virtualbox shared folder into your linux VM - is that correct? The mount type would be the same. Maybe check your `/etc/fstab` for PCSHARE

Comment: is `gdrive` a Google Drive folder? You probably don't want to mount a different file system inside of gdrive's weird virtual fs

Comment: I don't have a VM, I use linux distro directly, not a VM. But I installed rclone to have gdrive folder and I try to copy some files between my drive D to my home drive with that script.

Comment: Are you trying to copy files from `$BinDir` into gdrive? Why do you need to mount anything? Your mount command is missing the source, like in the brackets here `mount -t xfs [/dev/sdb1] /mnt/mountpoint`. "Mountname" means you probably used a named mount entry from `/etc/fstab` before. What source do you actually want to mount? The question says nothing about your drive D/home drive locations or types

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Are you trying to copy files from $BinDir into gdrive: YES.
cause i Got this ;  `mount: /home/james/gdrive/OpenWrt_builds/IPQ806X_master: can't find in /etc/fstab.`